# iOS app - can't click until momentum scroll stops

Tags: javascript, scroll, click

I'm building an iPad app that has links and other buttons which works fine.

HOWEVER if the user scrolls (ios native momentum scroll activates) and tries to click any links/buttons before scroll stops, it doesn't work.

In order for the clicks to work, the user either has to stop the momentum scroll or if they clicked before scroll stops, they would have to wait a few seconds then click again.

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution using fastclick.js

Then I ran into another issue: I needed certain sections of the app NOT to use fastclick. The answer to that problem was by creating a variable with the sections fastclick is to be attached and it will ignore all other sections.